# julia warning message: eval from module NamedTuples to DataFrames

Tags: julia

During the precompilation of the julia DataFrames packages, the following warning message occurred:

```
julia> using DataFrames

WARNING: eval from module NamedTuples to DataFrames:
Expr(:type, false, Expr(:<:, Expr(:curly, :_NT_col, :T1)::Any, NamedTuples.NamedTuple)::Any, Expr(:block, Expr(:::, :col, :T1)::Any, Expr(:tuple)::Any)::Any)::Any
  ** incremental compilation may be broken for this module **
```

The DataFrame package itself seems to function without a problem.
In my understanding, this warning occurred due to the recent update in DataStreams to v0.3.5 *(#75 Switch back to using NamedTuples package)*.

Unfortunately, I have found not much information on this problem. What are the implications of this warning and how safe is it to ignore this warning?

The warning occurred on julia v0.6.2 and v0.6.3. I used:

```
Julia Version 0.6.2
Commit d386e40c17* (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
DataFrames                    0.11.6
DataStreams                   0.3.5
NamedTuples                   4.0.2
```

**Edit**: The Problem has been solved with the updated DataStream Version v0.3.6. See github repo [DataStream v0.3.6](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataStreams.jl/commit/ae3306c1ecb8e1320669981a8b59d2034e706613) for the fix.

Comment: Is it possible this stems from the Python `namedtuple` module? [Raymond](https://www.pybay16.com/raymond-hettinger) more or less wrote that and in a presentation from '15, he admitted to using an `eval` in the `namedtuple` module. He also explains why:

Comment: > "... you looked at the source code and saw that I used eval and it makes you mad, doesn't it. Even though I chose it for sound business reasons like now everybody can understand the code. I never get a question on how named tuples work because they're self-documenting, it's also very easy to maintain and you can print out the template so you don't have to use eval at all. And, you can cut it out, run it through PyPy, run it through Scithon and get an optimized namedtuple."

Comment: Source: [Raymond Hettinger - Beyond PEP 8 -- Best practices for beautiful intelligible code - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M), from 48:45 onwards.

Comment: If so, we can conclude the `eval` is there with a reason and the writer, with lots of experience in the core of Python, has no problems with it. While he explains how to fix it in Python, this won't help you much in Julia. Considering you've already fixed it though, and how [Julia changed how Named Tuple type functionality](https://github.com/JuliaData/NamedTuples.jl) is done, the problem should not be reproducible anymore.